# Moving webpages and redirecting using 404 page to old pages

Tags: php, apache

I was looking for a way to move files from my root folder `/` to designated folder `/newFolder` while weeping this change hidden from users, for example, when going to

```
http://site.com/ABC
```

I want the browser to display content from

```
http://site.com/customerPages/ABC
```

but the client will see the following URL in his browser:

```
http://site.com/ABC
```

I've tried using `RewriteRule` but since the folder names aren't pre-defined I failed to do so.  Then I tried using `file_get_contents()` in my 404 page but it broke all the relative paths.

Finally I used the following code in my 404 page:

```
// Redirect customers to customers landing pages under /newFolder
if (strpos($message,'newFolder') === false) {
    $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/newFolder'.$message;
    echo '<frameset><frame src="/newFolder'.$message.'"></frameset>';
    exit();
} else {
    // correct the URL - remove the `/newFolder` bit
    $message = str_replace('/newFolder','',$message);
}
```

*$message - the requested URI*

I know that this solution is dirty, and i would love to improve it. Anyone knows how to?

Are there any problems with my design? are there any issues using `frameset` to display a webpage?

**EDIT**

I eventually stayed with my original solution (used the 404 page with frameset) to avoid from creating rules for all of the pages, and there for making the `.htaccess` heavier.

Comment: Was your rewrite rule "RewriteRule ^ABC customerPages/ABC"? That in your /.htaccess should work.

Comment: Just a small side note on the boolean expression in your condition - add another `=` so you have `=== false` because as of now `0 == false` will evaluate to `true`, see [Loose comparison with ==](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: @ErikNedwidek I don't want to hard-code the solution (listing my code or listing customer pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You Want have Different URL for Your client

You Can Use This code in htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/ABC/(.*?)/(.*)
RewriteRule ^ customerPages/%3 [L]
```

I Test It In My Web host Work correctly

Sample:
Virtual URL

http://sepidarcms.ir/ABC/Client1/image/logo.png

http://sepidarcms.ir/ABC/Client2/image/logo.png

http://sepidarcms.ir/ABC/Client3/image/logo.png

Real URL For All:

http://sepidarcms.ir/customerPages/image/logo.png

if You Want Can Remove ABC With a Little Change In This code

Comment: yes, but I have my own code, such as /images or /js that I don't want to move, and I don't want to hard-code the solution (listing my code or listing customer pages).

Comment: thanks for the update but i am looking for a different way, i have about 300 customer pages and i don't want to add 300 rules to the *.htaccess* file since it will make the apache slower...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have never used cakePHP, but this worked for me;

Files/folders;

```
./
    index.php
    images/
        so-logo.png
    newfolder/
        abc.php
```

Contents;

```
// .htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newfolder/$1.php [L]

// index.php
<? echo __file__; ?>
<br>
<img src="images/so-logo.png" width="100">

// abc.php
<? echo __file__; ?>
```

URL's outputs;

```
// index.php - http://localhost/rewrite/
D:\LAMP\www\rewrite\index.php
[logo]

// abc.php - http://localhost/rewrite/abc
D:\LAMP\www\rewrite\newfolder\abc.php
```

Comment: doesn't work for me since some of the cake calls go to non-existing folders and are processed by cake controllers, and this method is adding the `/newfolder` to the URI..